# Timepicker - set current time as default

Tags: html, knockout.js, datetimepicker

I'm using a timepicker element and binding it through data-bind. However, when page loads the timepicker input field has value "1:00" and I want to set current time as default value which can be changed.

```
<div class="date datetimepicker" style="position: relative" 
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm picker datetimepicker" id="timeOfControl" data-bind="timePicker: TimeOfControl
</div>
```

Comment: where is this timePicker plugin from? Is it your own custom handler? If not, please share the link of the documentation and I'll help with the knockout part

Comment: The input field is missing a close tag btw

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    $('#timeOfControl').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate:date
    });
});
```